# Mockito mockStatic

Tags: java, spring, mocking

I am trying to mock with Mockito a static method for my unit test, like this

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

....

    @PostConstruct
    public void post() {
        
        try (MockedStatic<JwtUtil> util = Mockito.mockStatic(JwtUtil.class)) {
            util.when( () -> JwtUtil.findSubject(any(Principal.class)))
                    .thenReturn(faker.rickAndMorty().character());
        }
    }
```

this is the method

```
public class JwtUtil {

    public static String findSubject(Principal principal) {
        JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken = (JwtAuthenticationToken) principal;
        Jwt jwtPrincipal = (Jwt) jwtAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();
        return jwtPrincipal.getSubject();
    }
```

I'm getting a null point exception, because method was not mocked

```
    at JwtUtil.findSubject(JwtUtil.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
```

Any ideas ? Could be Principal type ?

Comment: I would assume you need to call `@InjectMocks` on the bean that is using the static class. You are mixing SpringBootTests and MockitoTests. I am guessing that this is causing problems.

Comment: the mocking ends together with the try with resources block, which is why you should be mocking within the test method not in postConstruct